# ListView not getting displayed in Fragment but working onResume

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment which displays a Custom ListView. The Fragment is as follows -

```
    package com.grabstr.home;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.grabstr.common.Utils_Grabstr;
    import com.grabstr.database.DBhelper;
    import com.grabstr.search.Nearby_Search;
    import com.rey.material.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import com.tech.grabstr.R;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import com.grabstr.home.Rewards_Data;

    public class GrabItFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentCommunicator {

        Activity activity;
        ListView lv_grabit;
        RewardsAdapter rewardsAdapter;
        Context context;
        LinearLayout ll_error, ll_nointernet;
        private ActivityCommunicator activityCommunicator;
        //String final_quary = "";
        //DBhelper db_helper;
        //ArrayList<Locations_data> arr_Locations;
        ArrayList<Rewards_Data> arr_Rewards;
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipeView;

        com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView progress_wheel;
        //private Drawable[] mDrawables = new Drawable[2];

        public static GrabItFragment newInstance() {
            GrabItFragment fragment = new GrabItFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            context = getActivity();
            activityCommunicator = (ActivityCommunicator) context;
            ((Home) context).fragmentCommunicator = this;
            //db_helper = new DBhelper(context);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grabit_fragment, container, false);
            lv_grabit = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.grabItList);
            swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
            progress_wheel = (com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);
            //fab_image = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ivFilter);
            ll_error = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_error);
            ll_nointernet = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_nointernet);
            // lv_popular.setEmptyView(ll_error);
            if (!Utils_Grabstr.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {

                //fab_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lv_grabit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
swipeView.setColorScheme(R.color.orange);
        swipeView
                .setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {

                        if (Utils_Grabstr.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                            (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                                    ArrayList<Rewards_Data> result = new ArrayList<Rewards_Data>();
                                    if (rewardsAdapter == null) {

                                        rewardsAdapter = new RewardsAdapter(
                                                getActivity(), getActivity(),
                                                result);
                                        lv_grabit.setAdapter(rewardsAdapter);
                                        ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        progress_wheel
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    } else {
                                        rewardsAdapter.update_array(result);
                                        //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        progress_wheel
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        rewardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    //final_quary = "";
                                    //fab_image.setIcon(mDrawables[0], true);
                                    activityCommunicator
                                            .passDataToActivity("referesh");
                                }
                            }, 800);
                        }
                    }
                });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Utils_Grabstr.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {

            //if (final_quary.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

                //fab_image.setIcon(mDrawables[0], true);

                ArrayList<Rewards_Data> result = ((Home) context).arr_Rewards;
                if (result.size() > 0) {
                    ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    lv_grabit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (lv_grabit.getAdapter() == null) {
                        rewardsAdapter = new RewardsAdapter(getActivity(),
                                getActivity(), result);
                        lv_grabit.setAdapter(rewardsAdapter);
                        //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        if (rewardsAdapter == null) {

                            rewardsAdapter = new RewardsAdapter(getActivity(),
                                    getActivity(), result);
                            lv_grabit.setAdapter(rewardsAdapter);
                            progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            rewardsAdapter.update_array(result);
                            rewardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // lv_popular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // ll_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


        } else {

            //fab_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lv_grabit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void passDataToRewardFragment(ArrayList<Rewards_Data> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (result.size() > 0) {
            ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lv_grabit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (lv_grabit.getAdapter() == null) {
                rewardsAdapter = new RewardsAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity(),
                        result);
                lv_grabit.setAdapter(rewardsAdapter);
                //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                if (rewardsAdapter == null) {

                    rewardsAdapter = new RewardsAdapter(getActivity(),
                            getActivity(), result);
                    lv_grabit.setAdapter(rewardsAdapter);
                    //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                } else {
                    rewardsAdapter.update_array(result);
                    rewardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            lv_grabit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // init();
    }
    @Override
    public void passDataToFragment(ArrayList<Deal_data> result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

My Adapter is as follows -

```
package com.grabstr.home;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.grabstr.search.Special_Search;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.ImageLoadingListener;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;
import com.tech.grabstr.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RewardsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Rewards_Data> dd;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoadingListener animatedisplayListener = new AnimateDisplayListener();
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public RewardsAdapter(Context context, Activity activity,
            ArrayList<Rewards_Data> messages) {

        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.dd = messages;


        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.foodbg)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.foodbg)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.foodbg).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisc(true).considerExifParams(true).build();

    }

    public void update_array(ArrayList<Rewards_Data> chats_array_list) {
        this.dd = chats_array_list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dd.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return dd.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = (activity).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rewards_listrow, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rl_layParent2 = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.rl_layParent2);
            holder.img_reward = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_reward);
            holder.rewardstxt_tags = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rewardstxt_tags);
            holder.txt_Reward = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Reward);
            holder.txt_RewardsPercentage = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_RewardsPercentage);
            holder.txt_RewardsLocations = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_RewardsLocations);
            holder.txt_RewardsChance = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.txt_RewardsChance);
            holder.txt_Rewardstimings = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_Rewardstimings);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (!dd.get(position).getCategory().equals("")
                && dd.get(position).getCategory().length() > 2
                && !dd.get(position).getCategory().equalsIgnoreCase("undefined")) {
            holder.rewardstxt_tags.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.rewardstxt_tags.setText(dd.get(position).getCategory());
        } else
            holder.rewardstxt_tags.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.rewardstxt_tags.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent Special_Search = new Intent(context,
                        Special_Search.class);
                Special_Search.putExtra("deal_tag", dd.get(position).getCategory());
                context.startActivity(Special_Search);
            }
        });

        if (!dd.get(position).getName().equals(""))
            holder.txt_Reward.setText(dd.get(position).getName());
        else
            holder.txt_Reward.setText("N/A");
        if(dd.get(position).getCategory().equals("weekly") || dd.get(position).getCategory().equals("monthly")
                || dd.get(position).getCategory().equals("daily")){
        if(!dd.get(position).getClaims().equals(""))
            holder.txt_RewardsPercentage.setText("100%");
            else
            {
                float claims = Float.parseFloat(dd.get(position).getClaims());
                float quantity = Float.parseFloat(dd.get(position).getQuantity());
                float result = (quantity/claims);
                String finalresult = String.format("%.2f", result);
                int probability = Integer.parseInt(finalresult);
                holder.txt_RewardsPercentage.setText(probability*100 + "%");
            }
        holder.txt_RewardsChance.setText("chance of winning");
        }else
        {
            holder.txt_RewardsPercentage.setText(dd.get(position).getClaims());
            holder.txt_RewardsChance.setText("out of "+dd.get(position).getQuantity()+" applied");
        }
        if (!dd.get(position).getBrand_name().equals(""))
            holder.txt_RewardsLocations.setText(dd.get(position).getBrand_name());
        else
            holder.txt_RewardsLocations.setText("N/A");

        if (!dd.get(position).getImage_url().equals("")) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(dd.get(position).getImage_url(),
                    holder.img_reward, options, animatedisplayListener);
            //Log.e("Images", "URL: " + dd.get(position).getimgURL());
        }
        holder.txt_Rewardstimings.setText("");

        holder.rl_layParent2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout rl_layParent2;
        ImageView img_reward;
        TextView rewardstxt_tags, txt_Reward, txt_RewardsPercentage, txt_RewardsLocations,
        txt_RewardsChance, txt_Rewardstimings;

    }
    private static class AnimateDisplayListener extends
    SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections
        .synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
        Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

This is the first fragment when the app opens and the issue is that the list items appear when onResume is called, but not when the app opens. Could you please provide any input, I'm stuck on this since days!

The xml layout of grabit_fragment is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.tech.grabstr"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fragmentbggray"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/grabItList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
        android:id="@+id/progress_wheel"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/orange" />

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/ll_error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imgError"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_deals_found"/>

        <com.grabstr.fonts.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoResult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="OOPS. NO REWARDS FOUND!"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey_color"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/ll_nointernet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView  android:id="@+id/imgnointernet"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/no_internet"/>

        <com.grabstr.fonts.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoInternet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="INTERNET CONNECTION LOST"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey_color"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>     


</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm running an AsyncTask in the Home Activity which calls 2 fragments, one of the Fragment is shown above, onPostExecute I am parsing the JSON and passing it to the fragment , I am calling passDataToReward() which is implemented in the above fragment. Also posting onCreateView code for a comment -

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grabit_fragment, container, false);
        lv_grabit = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.grabItList);
        swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        progress_wheel = (com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);
        //fab_image = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ivFilter);
        ll_error = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_error);
        ll_nointernet = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll_nointernet);
        // lv_popular.setEmptyView(ll_error);
        if (!Utils_Grabstr.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {

            //fab_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lv_grabit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progress_wheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        swipeView.setColorScheme(R.color.orange);
        swipeView
                .setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {

                        if (Utils_Grabstr.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                            swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                            (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                                    ArrayList<Rewards_Data> result = new ArrayList<Rewards_Data>();
                                    if (rewardsAdapter == null) {

                                        rewardsAdapter = new RewardsAdapter(
                                                getActivity(), getActivity(),
                                                result);
                                        lv_grabit.setAdapter(rewardsAdapter);
                                        ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        progress_wheel
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                    } else {
                                        rewardsAdapter.update_array(result);
                                        //fab_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        ll_error.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        ll_nointernet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        progress_wheel
                                                .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        rewardsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    //final_quary = "";
                                    //fab_image.setIcon(mDrawables[0], true);
                                    activityCommunicator
                                            .passDataToActivity("referesh");
                                }
                            }, 800);
                        }
                    }
                });

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Its not dipsplaying in **onCreateView()** because you are not setting adapter, in **onResume()** you are setting the adapter.

Comment: @NigamPatro I have one more Fragment with the exact same code and it is working there. Are you sure that is all I'm missing?

Comment: Yup buddy. Once check your code, what you posted in **onCreateView()** , you are not setting any adpter.

Comment: @NigamPatro when OnCreateView is called, it should call passDataToRewardFragment(ArrayList), in that the adapter is being set, i tried setting the adapter in onCreateView() as you said but it still did not work. :(

Comment: Can you just post the code for **onCreateView()** changes.

Comment: @NigamPatro I have edited the question with more information and the code snip you asked for

Comment: But in **onCreateView()** , there is no call for passDataToRewardFragment().

Comment: @NigamPatro The call for passDataToRewardFragment() is from the Home Activity